# R sub select from a list of vectors using do.call, lapply or mapply?

Tags: r, lapply, mapply, do.call

I have the following data. `x` is a list of vectors and `indices` is a list of indices.

```
x = list(c("a", "b", "c", "a"), c("b", "x", "a", "c"))
indices = list(c(1, 2), c(3, 4))
```

What I want to do is step through each vector represented within the list `x` and sub select from that vector based on the `indices` vector. So the expected result is

```
a,b
a,c
```

I tried it with `mapply`

```
> mapply('[',x,indices)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "a" 
[2,] "b"  "c"
```

but thats not doing what I want it to. Any pointers? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close.  After indexing, the elements can be collapsed to a single string.  Here, I am using a wrapper (`toString`) for `paste(., collapse=', ')`

```
 f1 <- function(x,y) toString(x[y])
 mapply(f1,x,indices)
 #[1] "a, b" "a, c"
```